# Put cited references all in one bracket in Latex

Tags: citing, natbib, ieeetran, journal-publishing, cite-package

I am writing a paper in `IEEEtrans` format using Tex, and I use `\cite{cmm1,cmm2,cmm3,cmm5}`, but when compiling, Latex show them in separate brackets as `[1], [2], [3], [4]`.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Most likely if you posted a minimum working example (a "MWE") it would attract more answers. http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: Are you using a citation management package such as `cite` or `natbib`?

Comment: I'm not using anything...just the regular \cite given the IEEE style.

Comment: You should try loading the `cite` package. If you do that, issuing the command `\cite{cmm1,cmm2,cmm3,cmm5}` should produce `[1-4]` as its output.

Comment: This is by design: the IEEE specify that each reference number should have brackets, rather than the brackets appearing around the entire set of numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to generate the refereces with in a pair of square bracket, you can use the package `natbib` with option `numbers`. If you need sorting of reference and compressing using ndash, then the option `sort&compress` can be used.

```
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
```

A MWE which will work:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\title{Title}

\author{Author}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\blindtext. This shows how to cite \cite{cite1,cite2,cite3,cite4} in text.

\begin{thebibliography}{4}
\bibitem{cite1} First bib.

\bibitem{cite2} Second bib.

\bibitem{cite3} Third bib.

\bibitem{cite4} Fourth bib.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Output when `sort&compress` option is used:

[image]

Output when `sort&compress` option is not used:

[image]

There is also `cite` package when used `\usepackage{cite}` by replacing `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}` in the above MWE will yield the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know why when I use `\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}` it increases the font size of the references, so I get out of page limits!

Comment: @TinaJ: For that you need to update either you question with a MWE as show in my answer, which replicate exactly the problem.